# Pointwise and uniform as i understand

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Verify if this statement is true: 
The pointwise convergence depends on each point $x$, that is you need to count and fix every  $x$ before passing to the limit. On the other hand, uniform convergence is independent of $x$. Hence, the pointwise convergence is enough to cover a countable set $Q$ in the following sence $$ \forall x \in Q, ~~~~ f_n(x) \longrightarrow f(x)$$  where we took every single $x$ into account when we passed to the limit as we covered the set by writing $\forall x$ for each $x \in Q$ and not enough to cover  an uncoutable set like $[0,1]$, in such case you need a uniform convergence to generalise your convergence on $[0,1]$.

Comment: It is a rather vague statement, so it is very difficult to tell whether it is true or not. "The pointwise convergence is enough..." -- enough for what?

Comment: Not really. It depends on what "enough" means. For example, pointwise convergence of a family of sequences does not imply convergence of their sum, even though in this case the domain is countable. (The corresponding result *does* go through when the domain is finite.) Also, uniform convergence is typically overkill, but it is the simplest refinement of pointwise convergence so it is typically taught first.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, i just edited the question and explained the sence of enough :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to think about this is as follows.

**Pointwise at  $x$.**  Given any small quantity $\epsilon$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $f_n(x)$ differs from $f(x)$ by less than $\epsilon$ for  all $n>N$.

**Uniform.** The same integer $N$ can be used for all $x$.

It is important to realise that convergence can occur at every $x$ but for there to be no $N$ which works for  all $x$. Can you think of or construct an example?